# Can Partial Discharge occour in DC circuits?

Tags: ac, dc, dielectric-breakdown, partial-discharge

Partial discharge is a localized dielectric breakdown (DB) (which does not entirely bridge the space between the two conductors).

Hence, there will not be a global flow of current between the two conductors, as there is still isolation, but a local flow between two regions of the isolation (i.e., where the void starts and ends).

Over time partial discharge can erode the isolator and eventually turn into an electrical breakdown.
Now my question: As this process occurs over time, am I right to conclude that only an AC can sustain it, as there is a constant change of electrical potential between the two conductors.

On the contrary, in the DC circuit, partial discharges **cannot** occur as the potential difference between the two conductors is constant?

As an example consider an insulating solid material (dirt) with gas-filled voids.

Comment: Partial discharge *through what material*? Air? FR4? Dirt on FR4? Electrolyte?

Comment: I was not focus on a specific material, but on the general notion. If Partial discharge can happen in DC, where does the current flow?

Comment: To answer this question you need to post what the material is, because the breakdown and sustaining is dependent on what is between the electrodes. Current (charge/electrons) flows between any two potentials. How much current is dependent on what is between the electrodes, as the current increases, it is sufficent to cause arcing which happens when joule heating causes the material to vaporize and turn into a plasma. The plasma sustains even more current until the source voltage is pulled down or the plasma is extinguished.

Comment: I am not sure if I follow you, but let's consider as an example dirt as insulating material with gas-filled voids

Comment: PD is absolutely a thing in DC circuits and are very challenging to measure. Circuits with very high resistance and low capacitance (cables) can have extremely long time constants to charge before PD becomes evident.

Comment: I think winny you should answer the question. your comment made me understand now. The reason why PD is a thing in DC circuits is because we have extremely long time constanst!

Comment: I’ll try to write up a full answer for you tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it can. DC erodes conductors much quicker. Isolators are normaly not eroded but damaged by chemical processes, manufacturing faults or just bad design. Partial discharge should be in the top 3 causes for capacitor faults... at least that is what why they  kick the bucket... Its also happens in coils like relais or transformers.

PS: e.g. an already damaged cable isolation will not "erode" but a Partial discharge can like burn away even more isolation until it fails completly.

Comment: I  think the real question has to do with the notion that one end of the current path is in the middle of the dielectric, so where does that current go? How can you have dc current flow when one end of the path is in the middle of an insulating material?

Comment: Exactly @ElliotAlderson

Comment: (Don't try this...) If you place a 20kV supply, regardless of AC or DC, a fair distance apart but touching *any* insulating material, corona discharge will invariably make a "track" of the higher-conduction surface path.  If you have enough power and stop it quickly, you get a lightning-bolt-looking blemish on the surface.  If you let it go longer, the material carbonizes and shorts out.  Where is the conduction path? The material itself.

Comment: Yeah but I would describe this a complete discharge and not a partial discharge, as there is a complete flow of current between the two electrodes